# Why is $s-\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n = f\Longleftrightarrow~\forall g\in L_{\mu}^{\infty}: \lim_{n\to\infty} f_n g\, d\mu=\int fg\, d\mu$?

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence

We had some different definitions concerning convergence. And I am a bit confused about that. First of all I give you some preparing definitions and then the definitions I mean.

Let $E$ be a Banach space and $E^*:=\left\{L: E\to\mathbb{R}: L\text{ linear and continious}\right\}$ its dual space. $\mathcal{C}_{b}(\Omega)$ is the set of the continious functions $f\colon\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ that are bounded. $\mathcal{C}_K(\Omega)$ is the set of the continious functions $g\colon\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ with compact support.

> > **(1)** Let $E$ be a Banach space. A sequence $f_n\in E$ is called weakly convergent to $f\in E$, if
> >     $$
> > \forall L\in E^*: \lim_{n\to\infty}L(f_n)=L(f).
> > $$
> >     **(2)** Let $E$ be a Banach space. A sequence $L_n\in E^*$ is called weakly-*-convergent to $L\in E^*$ if
> >     $$
> > \forall f\in E: \lim_{n\to\infty}L_n(f)=L(f).
> > $$
> >     **(3)** Let $\Omega$ be a topological space. A sequence $\mu_n$ of finite Baire-measures is called weakly convergent to the finite Baire-measure $\mu$ if
> >     $$
> > \forall f\in\mathcal{C}_b(\Omega): \lim_{n\to\infty}\int f\, d\mu_n=\int f\, d\mu.
> > $$
> >     I.e. $\mu_n$ converges weakly-* to $\mu$ in $\mathcal{C}_b(\Omega)^*$. We write 
> >     $$
> > s-\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu_n=\mu.
> > $$
> >     **(4)** Let $\Omega$ be a topological space. A sequence $\mu_n$ of finite measures on $\sigma(\mathcal{C}_K(\Omega))$ is called vague weakly to the finite measure $\mu$ on $\sigma(\mathcal{C}_K(\Omega))$ if
> >     $$
> > \forall f\in\mathcal{C}_K(\Omega): \lim_{n\to\infty}\int f\, d\mu_n=\int f\, d\mu.
> > $$
> >     I.e. $\mu_n$ converges wekaly-* to $\mu$ in $\mathcal{C}_K(\Omega)$. We write 
> >     $$
> > v-\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu_n=\mu.
> > $$

---

Now the following example is given: Let $E=L_{\mu}^1$ with a $\sigma$-finite measure $\mu$. Then the dual space is isomorph to $L_{\mu}^{\infty}$, i.e. $E^*\simeq L_{\mu}^{\infty}$. Ok, I can follow up to here, this is an application of the Radon-Nikodým-theorem.

But now the script says:

So it is
$$
s-\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n=f\Longleftrightarrow~\forall g\in L_{\mu}^{\infty}: \lim_{n\to\infty}\int f_n g\, d\mu=\int fg\, d\mu.
$$

I cannot follow this equivalence on the basis of the four definitions I gave above.

$s-\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n=f$ means to me (when following definition (1))
$$
\forall g\in L_{\mu}^{\infty}: \lim_{n\to\infty} g(f_n)=g(f)
$$

But what is $g(f_n)$ resp. $g(f)$ and what means $\lim_{n\to\infty}g(f_n)=g(f)$? And why should this be equivalent to
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int f_n g\, d\mu=\int fg\, d\mu?
$$

---

Hope you can help me to clear away my confusion.

Greetings

Miro

Comment: I think $g(f)$ is by definition $\int gf\,d\mu$

Comment: But why? If $f\in L_{\mu}^1$ and $g\in L_{\mu}^{\infty}$ it is $f\colon\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ and $g\colon\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$

Comment: It's an abuse of notations. As @math32 answered, we denote the operator $T_g:f\to \int fg\,d\mu$ by simply writing $g(f)$.

Answer (score 1):

The isomorphism you are talking about is given by
$$
F\colon L_{\mu}^{\infty}\to (L_{\mu}^1)^*, g\mapsto F_g, F_g(f):=\int fg\, d\mu,
$$
so you have to identify $g$ with $F_g$.